# Undefined method debug for ActiveSupport: logging and debugging for lib files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a file in my lib directory, /lib/process_survey.rb, which defines a class ProcessSurvey.

Within a method called readsurvey, I try to write to the debug log.

```
Rails.logger.debug "Hello world"
```

However, I get an error:

```
undefined method `debug=' for #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x007fb728a31d58>
```

If I understand this correctly, the app is finding Logger.  But why doesn't it understand debug?

Comment: For me it works when i run it in console...